# Converting decimal to binary in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

The code is giving false answers. İf number equals 42, it turns it to 101010. Ok, it is true. But if number equals 4, it turns it to 99. I didn't find the mistake. How can i fix the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int i,digit,number=4;
    long long bin= 0LL;
    i=0;
    while(number>0)   
    {
          digit=number%2;
          bin+=digit*(int)pow(10,i);
          number/=2;
          i++;
    }
    printf("%d ",bin);
    getch();   
}
```

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", (int)pow(10, 2));` What do you get? Next try `printf("%g\n", pow(10, 2));` and see what you get. I'm guessing by the presence of `<conio.h>` that you are using a very old compiler (Turbo C?) and that its floating point support may not be as good as modern systems. This is entirely aside from the point that using floating point to solve this problem is very strange.

Comment: Much easier to use strings to represent binary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using floating point calculations for this. You are subject to the vagaries of floating point. When I ran your program with my compiler, the output was 100. But I guess your compiler treated the floating point `pow` differently.

A simple change to make the code behave, and use integer arithmetic only, would be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int digit,number=4;
    long long scale,bin= 0LL;
    scale=1;
    while(number>0)   
    {
          digit=number%2;
          bin+=digit*scale;
          number/=2;
          scale*=10;
    }
    printf("%lld ",bin);
    getch();   
}
```

But I'd rather see the binary built up in a string rather than an integer.

Comment: `%d` must be changed to `%lld` and either `digit` or `scale` should be changed to `long long`.

Comment: @doruk Fair enough. Much better is to switch to using strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simpler and easier approach to convert [decimal to binary number system](http://codeforwin.org/2015/08/c-program-to-convert-from-decimal-to-binary-number-system.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    long long decimal, tempDecimal, binary;  
    int rem, place = 1;  

    binary = 0;  

    /* 
     * Reads decimal number from user 
     */  
    printf("Enter any decimal number: ");  
    scanf("%lld", &decimal);  
    tempDecimal = decimal;  

    /* 
     * Converts the decimal number to binary number 
     */  
    while(tempDecimal!=0)  
    {  
        rem = tempDecimal % 2;  

        binary = (rem * place) + binary;  

        tempDecimal /= 2;  
        place *= 10;  
    }  

    printf("\nDecimal number = %lld\n", decimal);  
    printf("Binary number = %lld", binary);  

    return 0;  
}
```